# maximize the top element of the stack after performing exactly K operations

Tags: arrays, algorithm, data-structures, stack

Given a stack of N integers.You need to maximize the top element of the stack after performing exactly K operations.In one operation, you can either pop an element from the stack or push any popped element into the stack. If the stack becomes empty after performing K operations and there is no other way for the stack to be non-empty, print -1.

Input format :

The first line of input consists of two space-separated integers N and K.
The second line of input consists N space-separated integers denoting the elements of the stack. The first element represents the top of the stack and the last element represents the bottom of the stack.

Output format :

Print the maximum possible top element of the stack after performing exactly K operations.

Sample Input

6 4

1 2 4 3 3 5

Sample Output

4

Answer (score 1):

Pop k-1 elements in k-1 operations. Now for the last operation, either you can pop one more element, or can push one element from the popped elements.

So compare both the cases, if you pop element in kth operation, the element on top should be more than all first k-1 popped elements, otherwise for kth operation push the largest element from k-1 popped elements.

Comment: can you think of any test case in which output will be  -1. And what about K>N.For K>N the output will be maximum element Right?

Comment: k = 1, n = 1, solution is -1. Only case, otherwise you can also avoid popping second number.

Comment: for k > n, answer is largest number.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation so adding it answer.

1.
For k>n it's not compulsory that answer is largest number, as from given example :

3 5
1 2 3
K = 5, in first operation we pop 1, then pop 2,
now we have K = 3, and top of stack element is 3 
pop 3, K = 2,
push 3, K = 1, top of stack element = 3
so if here we pop 3 then K = 0 and stack is empty which will be -1 as answer according to question statement which will be wrong.
So coming back to scenario where K = 3 and st.top() = 3 and popped elements are 1,2
push 2, K = 2
pop 2, K = 1
push 2, K = 0
the answer i.e. max element is 2 after the 5 operation.

2.For n = 1 if value of K is odd then answer will be -1 else it will be the first element

Comment: The question has 'push any popped element into the stack' so you need not necessarily push recently popped element. So in your case, after popping 3, push 2 then 3.

Comment: Yeah..I made mistake reading about it..but I think point 2 is right, any comment regarding it.

Answer (score 0):

python3 code :

```
n,k = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
arr = [int(x) for x in input().split()]
if n == 1:
    if k%2 == 1:
        print(-1)
    else:
        print(arr[0])
elif k >= n:
    print(max(arr))
else:
    print(max(arr[k-2],arr[k]))
```